# How To display child comments under parent comment in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Currently child comments are not shown under parent comments
Below is the code

```
<ul class="comments-list">
                                <?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="my-4">
                                            <div class="comment-author-image">
                                                <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="search" class="search-icon-white">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="comment-text">
                                                <div class="comment-text-author"><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?></div>
                                                <div class="comment-text-content"><?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?></div>
                                                <div class="comment-text-date"><?php display_human_readable_time($comment->comment_date); ?></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
```

Comment: Does `$comments` contain the child comments as well?
You should be able to determine if it's a child comment or parent comment via:
`<?php if( $comment->comment_parent ) : ?>
// Child comment
<?php else: ?>
// Regular comment or parent comment
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Yes $comments have child comments also. Child comments must be shown inside parent comment

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by following code:

```
$args = array(
        'parent' => $comment_ID,
        'hierarchical' => true,
       );
    $child_comments = get_comments($args);
```

You can also refer this [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/).

Comment: Hi Tanmay, With your code reply comments(child comments) are shown below parent comment, but as a user we cant differentiate the comments as they are shown 1 below another. See screenshot how it is coming https://snipboard.io/1R9IHY.jpg